# PHP, la vista no me muestra todos los decimales

Tags: php, numberformat

Muy buenas.

Estoy haciendo un sistema de venta en PHP con MySQL. Cuando registro el consumo de un producto me sucede lo siguiente:

Si inserto 3.000,45, lo inserta bien. En la vista se ve 3.000,45 y en la base de datos se ve 3000,45. Todo correcto.

Si inserto 30.000,45, lo inserta mal. En la vista se ve 30.000,40 y en la base de datos se ve 30000.4.

Si inserto 300.000,45, lo inserta mal. En la vista se ve 300.000,00 y en la base de datos se ve 300000.

Imagen de la vista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagen de la base de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código de la vista es:

```
     foreach ($mostrarPaneles as $key => $value){

      $value["energia"] = number_format($value["energia"], 2, ',', '.');

      echo '<tr>
      <td>'.($key+1).'</td>
      <td>'.$value["energia"].'</td>
```

Aquí hago el insert de la ventana modal.

```
    <input type="number" class="form-control input-lg" name="nuevoPorciento" min="0" step="any" placeholder="Ingresar energía/h" required>
```

Del controller este es el preg_match:

```
preg_match('/^[0-9,.]+$/', $_POST["nuevoPorciento"])
```

Gracias de antemano por vuestro tiempo.

Comment: ¿Y cómo guardas esos valores en la BD, la columna es de tipo ```decimal(10,2)```? porque si en la BD no te lo está guardando bien, en la vista tampoco va saber si ```30000.4``` son ```30000.45``` o ```30000.40```, empezaría a solucionar primero para que te guarde bien los valores en la BD

Comment: Puedes aportar tu propia respuesta explicando lo que te soluciono el problema así puede servir si alguien tiene un problema similar o si hay alguna respuesta que te lo soluciono el problema la puedes aceptar. Al usar decimal, puedes especificar cuanto números y decimales deseas :). Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

Prueba esto @Cristo

```
if (!preg_match('/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/', "100"))
```

El `$` determina el "final de una cadena": http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php

Esto te mirara los dos digitos de los decimales.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he podido solucionar. En la base de datos el campo con el que trabajaba lo había puesto del tipo FLOAT. Todo fue cambiar el tipo de FLOAT a DECIMAL (10,2).

Gracias por vuestra ayuda.